# Conditionally sum dynamic columns in r

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to conditionally sum across many columns depending on if they are greater than or less than 0. I am surprised I cannot find a `dplyr` or `data.table` work around for this. I want to calculate 4 new columns for a large data.frame (columns to calculate are at bottom of post).

```
dat2=matrix(nrow=10,rnorm(100));colnames(dat2)=paste0('V',rep(1:10))

dat2 %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  select_if(function(col){mean(col)>0}) %>%
  mutate(sum_pos=rowSums(.))  ##Obviously doesn't work
```

These are the simple statistics I want to calculate (yes; these apply statements work, but there are other things in my dplyr chain I want to do, so thats why I am looking for a `dplyr` or `data.table` way. The columns that are positive or negative *for each given row* are different, so I cannot grab a list of columns (must be done dynamically, by row).

```
#Calculate these, but in a dplyr chain?
n_pos=apply(dat2,1,function(x) sum((x>0)))
n_neg=apply(dat2,1,function(x) sum((x<0)))
sum_pos=apply(dat2,1,function(x) sum(x[(x>0)]))
sum_neg=apply(dat2,1,function(x) sum(x[(x<0)]))
```

Comment: `rowSums(replace(dat2, dat2 < 0, 0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need `rowwise` with `rowSums` as `rowSums` can do the sum without any groupings

```
library(dplyr)
dat2 %>%
   as.data.frame() %>%  
   select_if(~ is.numeric(.) && mean(.) > 0) %>% 
   mutate(sum_pos = rowSums(.))
```

---

Based on the description, it seems that it is not the `mean` condition, but related to rowwise, `sum` of the positive and negative values separately

```
dat2 %>%
   as.data.frame %>%
   mutate(sum_pos = rowSums(. * NA^(. < 0), na.rm = TRUE),
           sum_neg = rowSums(.[1:10] * NA^(.[1:10] > 0), na.rm = TRUE) )
```

Comment: This isn't matching the sum_pos vector obtained from `apply`

Comment: @K.J.J.K  In the `apply`, you are not using the `mean` condition and it is a different condition.  Which one are you looking for?

Comment: My strategy revolved around trying to taking the mean of a column of 1 to use select_if (hence, why I used mean in the select_if statement)

Comment: @K.J.J.K  Now, it should work with the `apply` solutiion

Comment: In English, is your statement multiplying by NA if `.` is greater than or less than 0, and then passing that vector (full of numbers and NAs) to rowSums?

Comment: @K.J.J.K  It is just a way to replace the value that are negative or positive to NA when we do the sum of postive and negative.  Another option is `replace` as in the comments